# finding LCP of two strings in constant time and linear space

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, prefix

This is the problem:

 Suppose **S** is a set of strings and we know the total length of all strings in **S** in **n**. We must find a data structure with space **O(n)** that finds LCP(s,t) in **O(1)** which LCP is the longest common prefix between strings **s,t**.

At first I thought I could use hashing since we can check numbers in constant time and find sub-strings in constant time if we prehashed strings.But I don't think this would work since it needs more space and after a little searching I found out that the solution probably lies in using Trie's,Suffix arrays and maybe LCA and RMQ. I think I'm close to the answer but don't know how these concepts can work together to make a data structure that give LCP fast!

Thanks for reading

Comment: Can we assume that the length of each string is `sqrt(n)` and that there are `sqrt(n)` strings?

Comment: @Yonlif I don't think so. we just know that the total length of all of them is `n`

Comment: I was thinking about heavy light decomposition with strings longer then `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: @Yonlif like compressing a trie?

Comment: What are s and t?  Because if they're strings then you can't even recognize them in constant time. If they're something that can be mapped to internal nodes in constant time, then you can do an LCA query on a trie.

Comment: A trie will do it in `O(length of prefix)`.  Given that you can't construct a string to return faster than that, I am thinking that this has to be the answer.  Is there a phrase like "fixed length strings" somewhere in the original description?

Comment: So would it be allowed to use whatever O(....) to **fill** that data structure with data?

Comment: The reply to that statement would be "Yes, that sounds like a good plan!". And then, if someone asks "Well, what is that data structure?" I would reply with "Oh, you were asking a question? Have you watched Jeopardy at all?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I know the answer they are looking for.

First, construct a trie for all of the strings.  Each node in the trie can include a pointer to a string starting with that prefix, and a length. Map each string to the final node in the trie that that string winds up on.

Now when given a pair of strings (which presumably you are told as string `i` and string `j`) the problem of returning a string is a question of finding the least common ancestor, then returning the pair `(pointer_to_start_of_string, length)`.

But a trie can be written as a tree, and then Tarjan's off line lowest Common Ancestors Algorithm (see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tarjans-off-line-lowest-common-ancestors-algorithm/) can be used to preprocess that tree to answer LCA questions very quickly.

It is technically not `O(1)`. However it is `O(inverse_ackermann(n))` which can be treated as a fairly small constant for any computer that fits in the observable universe.

Comment: Trajan's LCA is an offline algorithm that cannot answer arbitrary individual queries in that time, even after preprocessing.  There is a way to do it in constant time after preprocessing with linear space by using a Euler tour of the tree to reduce the problem to a range-minimum query.  See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-lca-in-binary-tree-using-rmq/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query